# Error when using Highcharts with Angular 2

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using [angular2-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts)
The `component.ts` file is as below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'emotions',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/emotions/emotions.component.html',
    providers: [EmotionsService],
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class EmotionsComponent {
    constructor(private emotionsService: EmotionsService) {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: HighchartsOptions;
}
```

In my template file

```
<chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

package.json file has the following alongwith other angular dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2-highcharts": "0.2.1"
  },
```

I have run `npm install` and angular2-highcharts has been install in `node_modules` folder.

I get the following error:

```
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/angular2-highcharts 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried to change the `systemjs.config.js` file to

```
map: {
            'angular2-highcharts': 'node_modules/angular2-highcharts'
}
```

However, I started getting the following error:

```
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-highcharts/ 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

EDIT

I added this in the `system.config.js` file

```
map:{
'angular2-highcharts': 'node_modules/angular2-highcharts/node_modules/highcharts/index.js',
}
```

I get the following error

```
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-highcharts/dist/index 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried changing  `index` -> `index.js`. It works on it but then gives the same error on other js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following things:

**systemjs.config.js**

```
map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            'angular2-highcharts': 'node_modules/angular2-highcharts',
            'highcharts': 'node_modules/highcharts'
}

packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-highcharts': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'highcharts': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
}
```

Remove the directives from the components file

Add the following in the `app.module.ts` file

```
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CHART_DIRECTIVES
    ],
})
```